# Getting -"Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token" and Access Denied while using Graph API to upload files to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, azure, graph-api, python

Initially when I tried to generate the token using the URL - `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-id/oauth2/v2.0/token` I was able to fetch the Bearer token using grant_type, client_id, scope and client_secret in the body.

But when I tried to fetch the drive_id using the URL - `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives` and Authorization in Headers, I am facing the following error :

```
"error": {
"code": "AccessDenied",
"message": "Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token.",
"innerError": {
"date": "2022-12-12T10:44:02",
"request-id": "45bxxxxxxxxxxx38e3c23e38",
"client-request-id": "45b1xxxxxxxxx8-7d38e3c23e38"
}
}
}
```

The permissions I granted are:

[image]

I tried to decode the token as well through the decoder site but could not find any roles.

I am not able to figure out the mistake.
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

need to be an aplication and not a delegated